# Sparse tool not detecting any erros/warnings on drivers/staging directory

Tags: c, linux, command-line, linux-kernel, sparse-matrix

I want to find out any warnings regarding coding style issues or logical bugs in drivers/staging directory in Linux kernel. To do this I am using Sparse tool.

However, I am not able to see any warnings/bugs in drivers/staging. But it detects warnings/bugs in other directories such as drivers/USB, etc.

Are there really no warnings/errors in staging directory or am I missing something special which needs to be taken care here before anything is seen?

1. I installed the sparse tool by following the instructions mentioned [here.](https://kernelnewbies.org/Sparse)
2. I cloned the Linux-next by following the instructions mentioned [here.](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/linux-next.html)
3. I copied the configuration by using following command:

   ```
   ~>cp /boot/config-`uname -r` .config
   ```
4. I ran the sparse using following command:

   ```
   ~>make -j4 C=1 M=drivers/staging > logfile.txt 2>&1
   ```

[Edit 1: I have also tried it with `C=2`.]

5. When I looked into the file `logfile.txt`, I found out there are no warnings/bugs.

When I followed the same procedure for `drivers/usb` just to check if it works on some other directory, I was able to see lots of warnings.

Could anybody please help on with this problem?
TIA.